# Clear Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

When the user presses the backspace key, I want the textbox and the datagridview to clear. With this code that I have, I have to press the backspace key twice in order for the datagridview to clear.

```
private void txtMusicianName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
            {

                e.Handled = false;
                gridSelectMusician.Rows.Clear();
                txtMusicianName.Clear();


            }
            
        }
```

EDIT: I changed my code accordingly. I also have a db call: `` "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `Email` LIKE '%" + txtMusicianName.Text + "%' OR `Name`LIKE '%" + txtMusicianName.Text + "%'" `` I tried adding in `if (txtName.Text != " ")` then make the database call. With that code, I get half of the result I want. If a user types a space nothing happens which is good but when the user backspaces then all of the names appear again. How do I prevent the names from showing up like that?

Comment: Code works as posted, so you have something else going on.  I would favor the KeyDown event: `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)`.  `txtMusicianName.Text.Trim();` is a function, not a method, so you are ignoring the results.  Pointless anyway since the line above it already clears it out.

Comment: I changed my code accordingly. I also have a db call: ```"SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `Email` LIKE '%" + txtMusicianName.Text + "%' OR `Name`LIKE '%" + txtMusicianName.Text + "%'"``` I tried adding in `if (txtName.Text != " ")` then make the database call. With that code, I get half of the result I want. If a user types a space nothing happens which is good but when the user backspaces then all of the names appear again. How do I prevent the names from showing up like that?

Comment: Do use sql parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Try `if (txtName.Text.Trim().Length > 0) {...}`